# Has the number of viewers that see a question changed in the last year or so?

Tags: discussion

It seems that, in the past, questions I've posted would receive a range of about 25-100 views in an hour for certain tags.

But in the last year or so, it seems like my questions only have 1 to 5 views per hour on the same topic.

Has something changed in the last year that would affect views?

Comment: https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends?tags=flash%2Cflex%2Cactionscript-3

Comment: I agree, also it seems like refreshing StackOverflow's home page yields fewer new questions than I feel like it did before

Comment: We're running out of questions that can be asked.

Comment: @Tschallacka people seem fine with asking questions that have already been asked, though.

Comment: Too true. But they get closed as duplicates pretty fast too.

Comment: I've noticed the AS3 has descended in fame and fortune but my recent question(s) that included the HTML tag, a subject that has risen over time according to insights but has received less exposure, was what prompted this inquiry.

Comment: @Tschallacka are you saying we've filled the infosphere er the stackoverflow-sphere?

Comment: @Tschallacka isn't it good? Internet has made it possible to find the fix to a problem from someone else who has already done it :) and a duplicate question proves it... The requirement is to solve a problem, not to have a working question :)

Comment: @Nitlin yea but the side effect might be that less users hang around and become "hooked"  whilst hunting for fake internet points because your question gets closed so fast. Just a theory though

Comment: Your last three questions are about a completely dead technology. So if this post was thought of because of those questions, I wouldn't be amazed. At all.

Comment: Html is a very high traffic tag. I monitor the live feed for that tag every now and then, and it is fairly easy for questions to be pushed off the front page quickly.